# HDInsight with Azure Blob Storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-hdinsight, cortana-intelligence

I have been trying to get this to work for a while now so would appreciate some help.  I am using the following:

- HDInsight Emulator
- Have set the default file system of the emulator in the core-site.xml to point to my Azure Storage Account
- The problem started when I deployed to my HDInsight cluter. It uploaded the mapper perfectly, then for some reason returns an http 404 but I have no clue as to why.  To debug I decided to point my HDInsight emulator to my Azure Storage account      using wasb in the hope of getting a more descriptive error.  I did and the error I got was the following : java.io.exception: Incomplete HDFS URI, no host: dhfs"///user/faheem/dotnetcli...    I know my default file system is connecting to azure because when I browse my azure storage I see my local machine has uploaded the mapper code.  It bombs after that.     Also when connecting to my emulator without the azure blob storage (i.e. the native HDFS filesystem) i get my map reduce code to work perfectly.  Please help!!!
- My code is a hello world application as follows

  ```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using Microsoft.Hadoop.MapReduce;


  namespace ZA_Provinces_Vertices_Test
  {
      internal class Program
      {
          private static Uri _azureCluster = new Uri("");
          private static string _clusterUserName = "";
          private static string _clusterPassword = "";
          private static string _hadoopUserName = "";

          // Azure Storage Information.
          private static string _azureStorageAccount = "storage.blob.core.windows.net";

          private static string _azureStorageKey =
              "{Key}";

          private static string _azureStorageContainer = "storagecontainer";
          private static bool _createContinerIfNotExist = false;

          private static bool _cloudIndicator = false;


          private static void Main(string[] args)
          {
              //var result = ProvinceShapeFile.PointInProvince(26.6337895, -27.7573934);//Longitude, Latitude

              //Console.WriteLine(result);
              //Console.ReadLine();

              //var inputArray = new[]
              //{
              //    "200000000|23.168|-27.504",
              //    "200000001|23.169|-27.504"
              //};

              IHadoop hadoop;

              hadoop = _cloudIndicator ? ConnectAzure() : ConnectLocal();

              var result = hadoop.MapReduceJob.ExecuteJob<MyCustomHadoopJob>();
              //var output = StreamingUnit.Execute<MyCustomMapper>(inputArray);

              //foreach (var mapperResult in output.MapperResult)
              //{
              //    Console.WriteLine(mapperResult);
              //}
          }

          private static IHadoop ConnectLocal()
          {
              return Hadoop.Connect();
          }

          private static IHadoop ConnectAzure()
          {
              return Hadoop.Connect(_azureCluster,
                  _clusterUserName,
                  _hadoopUserName,
                  _clusterPassword,
                  _azureStorageAccount,
                  _azureStorageKey,
                  _azureStorageContainer,
                  _createContinerIfNotExist);
          }

          private static HadoopJobConfiguration LocalConfig()
          {
              HadoopJobConfiguration config = new HadoopJobConfiguration();
              config.InputPath = "Input/sqrt";
              config.OutputFolder = "Output/sqrt";
              config.DeleteOutputFolder = true;

              return config;
          }

          private static HadoopJobConfiguration AzureConfig()
          {
              HadoopJobConfiguration config = new HadoopJobConfiguration();
              config.InputPath =
                  "wasb://{container}@{storage}.blob.core.windows.net/user/faheem/ZAProvinceFromPoint/Input";
              config.OutputFolder =
                  "wasb://{container}@{storage}.blob.core.windows.net/user/faheem/ZAProvinceFromPoint/Output";
              config.DeleteOutputFolder = false;

              config.DeleteOutputFolder = false;

              return config;
          }

          public class MyCustomHadoopJob : HadoopJob<MyCustomMapper>
          {
              public override HadoopJobConfiguration Configure(ExecutorContext context)
              {
                  //return _cloudIndicator ? AzureConfig() : LocalConfig();

                  return AzureConfig();
              }
          }

          public class MyCustomMapper : MapperBase
          {
              public override void Map(string inputLine, MapperContext context)
              {
                  var fields = inputLine.Split(new[] {"|"}, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();
                  double longitude = double.Parse(fields[1]);
                  double latitude = double.Parse(fields[2]);

                  string label = "Dummy"; //ProvinceShapeFile.PointInProvince(longitude, latitude);

                  string processedLine = String.Format("{0}|{1}", inputLine, label);

                  context.EmitKeyValue(processedLine, null);
                  //throw new NotImplementedException();
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Sanity check. Does your cluster have access to the storage account you are referencing?

Comment: Yep it does.  Reason i say this is two fold: 1) I created the storage account and cluster together and hence the default storage is the created storage account 2) The executable of the mapper gets uploaded to the blob storage its only after the executable gets uploaded does the job bomb out.    Any other suggestions.  Really desperate here